# Django query set complex order - union destroy order

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I am new to Python and Django. I have a list of items. Each item has 2 fields: `start_date` and `update_date`.
I am trying to query the items with the following order:

1. If start_date > today, order by `start_date` and than by `update_date`
2. Else (start_date <= today), order by `update_date` and than by `start_date`

I end up with the following query:

```
today = date.today()
all = m.items.objects.annotate(updated_at_date=TruncDate('updated_date'))
upcoming = all.filter(start__gte=today).order_by('start_date', '-updated_date')
started = all.filter(start__lt=today).order_by('-updated_date', 'start_date')
queryset = upcoming.union(started)
```

But when I print the results, I get it in different order. However, if I return only `upcoming` or only `started`, I get good ordering.

I think that Union destroy my ordering. What is wrong in my query? How can I fix that?